# how to put the dynamic returned html stuff inside another html file?

Tags: php, javascript, html, yii

the situation is like this, i was asked to use the header and footer of a dynamic site
made up of yii into another site hosted in a different server/host..
i created a controller and view in the dynamic site, now the question is
how to call that within the other site to use it , let's say the site is html or php ?
given this example url of the controller and action that i created

```
http://www.example.com/controller/display/header
http://www.example.com/controller/display/footer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, isn't going to work in the context your thinking. More so if its PHP based, as your not going to get the PHP functionality that makes the header or footer what it might be. As PHP renders server side when called on.

You could if its static HTML only maybe use cURL to access the file, and get the contents of it (again, the rendered HTML if php based). But other than that, there is so many things from the browser side to the server side of the remote server that are going to hinder your ability of doing what I think your trying to do, cause if it was that easy people would be hijacking sites left and right..

You could in concept open these remote locations in a frame/iframe but you won't have control over there content. I'd say if you are the owner of both sites in question or working in collaboration with the other site owner. Then you two should come up with a means of delivering the content of footer/header to your site, that doesn't break so many policies and risk serious security breaches.

In all though I can't imagine why you wouldn't just clone the look/feel through normal templating via HTML/CSS. Anything else just sounds a bit shaddy.

SomeKittens makes a valid point. But I just wanted to put my 2 cents in.

Comment: i guess you're right, am gonna talk to the dev of the other site, coz i don't have any idea how the structure of their site is..all i was asked is to give them header and footer of the dynamic site that am working on

Comment: Maybe all they want is just 2 files, one thats the header with the HTML/CSS and likewise with the footer. Where the CSS, and images are all full URL length of where they can be located on your server so they can just load these 2 files up on there server and use them respectively towards what ever agreement you have with them.

Comment: what they told me before was, they want the header and footer, so that they can use it in their current site and the future sites that they will be building, the header and footer should be hosted by the site that am working on....any idea what to do ?

Comment: make 2 different files, one thats the visual header of your site, and one thats the visual footer of your site. I'd say static HTML no php server side stuff. Then, if I am to assume what they are asking for, they may call these in through frames, or through a cURL method like I had mentioned. Theres no good logic that I can see at the moment just guessing why they would want it that way though.

Comment: another thing with this is that, my site is powered by yii framework..if you have used this framework before, you said create two different files, html, that means, they are view files...but the question is, how am i gonna let them display these header/footer view files in their site ?

Comment: As such with any MVC you can server static files, outside of the MVC pattern. Just create 2 new files on your server somewhere outside of the main folder for YII, unfortunately I am not extremely well versed with YII, but I have used my share of MVC's all around of which have the ability to ignore the pattern for files that otherwise exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `include` over `http`, but you'll need to edit your php.ini to set `allow_url_include=1`.

However, why can't you copy the files over to the second server?  Going cross-site like this is rather rude, as you'll be using the first server's bandwidth.

Comment: actually, I already did that...but someone suggested me to do this ..thanks for the reply